# How to automate docker to run script within container and notify completion to host?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to automate the build process of my application through the following steps:

1. Launch my `build-system` container that has all dependencies and scripts for making the final exe of my application.
2. Within the build-system container fire a bash script that starts the build process.
3. When the build completes, transfer the exe to the host machine either by using `docker cp` or by attaching a volume while launching the container.
4. Transfer the exe to a new `dist-system` container, which is essentially the final image that will be stored in Docker hub.
5. Install the application within the dist-system, make custom configurations by firing another bash script in that container.
6. When step 5 completes, get back to the host machine and run `docker commit` of the dist-system container and then `docker push` the image to Docker hub from the host machine.

My question relates specifically to points 3 and 6 where I need to know that the bash scripts have completed execution within the containers.  Only then I would like to fire docker commands in the host machine.  Is there a way in which docker can be notified of bash script execution within containers?

Comment: This entire sequence sounds like a very typical two-stage `docker build`, and you should research how that works.  You probably should never use `docker commit` directly (though this sequence is better than most).  `docker exec` also isn't intended to be the core path to doing things in Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker run` is synchronous, and by default will block until the docker container exits.

For example, if the `build-system` Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY ./build.sh /build.sh

VOLUME /data

CMD ["/build.sh", "/data/test.out"]
```

With `build.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 5
echo "Hello world!" >> "$1"
exit 0 # docker run will exit with this code, you can use this to check if your build was successful
```

Running `docker run --rm -v /your/work/directory/build-output:/data build-system` will wait 5 seconds and then exit, and `/your/work/directory/build-output/test.out` will have been created.

Comment: `docker build` is synchronous too.